# Ubuntu 16.04 Error occurred while editing grub-efi-amd64-signed and shim-signed

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, grub-efi

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 long time ago. It worked perfectly fine till yesterday. While performing sudo-apt-get upgrade I get this error:

```
Error occurred while editing 
grub-efi-amd64-signed 
shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can somebody help me?

Here is the complete output of the console:

```
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../grub-efi-amd64_2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von grub-efi-amd64 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16) über (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../grub-common_2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von grub-common (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16) über (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16) ...
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../os-prober_1.70ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von os-prober (1.70ubuntu3.3) über (1.70ubuntu3.3) ...
Trigger für systemd (229-4ubuntu21.1) werden verarbeitet ...
Trigger für ureadahead (0.100.0-19) werden verarbeitet ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Trigger für man-db (2.7.5-1) werden verarbeitet ...
grub-common (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16) wird eingerichtet ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
grub-efi-amd64 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16) wird eingerichtet ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: Fehler: /boot/efi scheint keine EFI-Partition zu sein.
.
Failed: grub-install --target=x86_64-efi  
WARNING: Bootloader is not properly installed, system may not be bootable
Grub-Konfigurationsdatei wird generiert …
Warnung: Werte ungleich 0 für »GRUB_TIMEOUT« werden, falls »GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT« aktiviert ist, nicht mehr unterstützt.
Linux-Abbild gefunden: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
initrd-Abbild gefunden: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-32-generic
Linux-Abbild gefunden: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-42-generic
initrd-Abbild gefunden: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-42-generic
Windows Boot Manager auf /dev/sda1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi gefunden
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
erledigt
grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.66.16+2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16) wird eingerichtet ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: Fehler: /boot/efi scheint keine EFI-Partition zu sein.
.
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 Unterprozess installiertes post-installation-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurück
shim-signed (1.33.1~16.04.1+13-0ubuntu2) wird eingerichtet ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: Fehler: /boot/efi scheint keine EFI-Partition zu sein.
.
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes shim-signed (--configure):
 Unterprozess installiertes post-installation-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurück
os-prober (1.70ubuntu3.3) wird eingerichtet ...
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Sorry that it's in german, i dont know how to change the console language to english.

Answer (score 0):

ok I found a programm called "Boot Repair". It fixed the problem!
Link to the programm if somebody has a similar problem:
[LINK](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)